# Pandas Dataframe: Add mean and std columns to every column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I would like to add a mean and a std column to every column of a dataframe. Unfortunately my code replaces the original columns by the mean and std ones.

```
np.random.seed(50)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,size=(30, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
print df
```

df

```
    A  B  C
0   0  0  1
1   4  6  5
2   6  6  5
3   2  7  4
4   3  6  4
5   1  5  0
6   6  3  2
7   3  3  3
8   2  0  3
9   2  0  3
10  0  0  7
11  3  8  7
12  4  4  0
13  0  3  3
14  1  4  5
15  7  0  3
16  5  6  1
17  4  4  4
18  5  4  6
19  3  0  5
20  8  3  6
21  2  8  8
22  5  4  7
23  8  4  4
24  2  1  8
25  7  1  5
26  8  3  3
27  5  3  6
28  8  6  0
29  8  2  1
```

Here's my code from:

> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html

```
r = df.rolling(window=5)
print 'Agg mean and sdt df'
print r['A', 'B', 'C'].agg([np.mean, np.std])
print
```

Output

Agg mean and sdt df

```
      A              B              C          
   mean       std mean       std mean       std
0   NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN
1   NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN
2   NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN
3   NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN
4   3.0  2.236068  5.0  2.828427  3.8  1.643168
5   3.2  1.923538  6.0  0.707107  3.6  2.073644
6   3.6  2.302173  5.4  1.516575  3.0  2.000000
7   3.0  1.870829  4.8  1.788854  2.6  1.673320
8   3.0  1.870829  3.4  2.302173  2.4  1.516575
9   2.8  1.923538  2.2  2.167948  2.2  1.303840
10  2.6  2.190890  1.2  1.643168  3.6  1.949359
11  2.0  1.224745  2.2  3.492850  4.6  2.190890
12  2.2  1.483240  2.4  3.577709  4.0  3.000000
13  1.8  1.788854  3.0  3.316625  4.0  3.000000
14  1.6  1.816590  3.8  2.863564  4.4  2.966479
15  3.0  2.738613  3.8  2.863564  3.6  2.607681
16  3.4  2.880972  3.4  2.190890  2.4  1.949359
17  3.4  2.880972  3.4  2.190890  3.2  1.483240
18  4.4  2.190890  3.6  2.190890  3.8  1.923538
19  4.8  1.483240  2.8  2.683282  3.8  1.923538
20  5.0  1.870829  3.4  2.190890  4.4  2.073644
21  4.4  2.302173  3.8  2.863564  5.8  1.483240
22  4.6  2.302173  3.8  2.863564  6.4  1.140175
23  5.2  2.774887  3.8  2.863564  6.0  1.581139
24  5.0  3.000000  4.0  2.549510  6.6  1.673320
25  4.8  2.774887  3.6  2.880972  6.4  1.816590
26  6.0  2.549510  2.6  1.516575  5.4  2.073644
27  6.0  2.549510  2.4  1.341641  5.2  1.923538
28  6.0  2.549510  2.8  2.049390  4.4  3.049590
29  7.2  1.303840  3.0  1.870829  3.0  2.549510
```

And what I am looking for is columns (and data) being:

```
    A  A_mean  A_std  B  B_mean  B_std  C  C_mean  C_std
```

I cannot find a solution for 'adding' these columns.

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [18]: res = df.rolling(5).agg(['mean','std'])

In [19]: res.columns = res.columns.map('_'.join)

In [54]: cols = np.concatenate(list(zip(df.columns, res.columns[0::2], res.columns[1::2])))

In [55]: cols
Out[55]:
array(['A', 'A_mean', 'A_std', 'B', 'B_mean', 'B_std', 'C', 'C_mean', 'C_std'],
      dtype='<U6')

In [56]: res.join(df).loc[:, cols]
Out[56]:
    A  A_mean     A_std  B  B_mean     B_std  C  C_mean     C_std
0   0     NaN       NaN  0     NaN       NaN  1     NaN       NaN
1   4     NaN       NaN  6     NaN       NaN  5     NaN       NaN
2   6     NaN       NaN  6     NaN       NaN  5     NaN       NaN
3   2     NaN       NaN  7     NaN       NaN  4     NaN       NaN
4   3     3.0  2.236068  6     5.0  2.828427  4     3.8  1.643168
5   1     3.2  1.923538  5     6.0  0.707107  0     3.6  2.073644
6   6     3.6  2.302173  3     5.4  1.516575  2     3.0  2.000000
7   3     3.0  1.870829  3     4.8  1.788854  3     2.6  1.673320
8   2     3.0  1.870829  0     3.4  2.302173  3     2.4  1.516575
9   2     2.8  1.923538  0     2.2  2.167948  3     2.2  1.303840
10  0     2.6  2.190890  0     1.2  1.643168  7     3.6  1.949359
11  3     2.0  1.224745  8     2.2  3.492850  7     4.6  2.190890
12  4     2.2  1.483240  4     2.4  3.577709  0     4.0  3.000000
13  0     1.8  1.788854  3     3.0  3.316625  3     4.0  3.000000
14  1     1.6  1.816590  4     3.8  2.863564  5     4.4  2.966479
15  7     3.0  2.738613  0     3.8  2.863564  3     3.6  2.607681
16  5     3.4  2.880972  6     3.4  2.190890  1     2.4  1.949359
17  4     3.4  2.880972  4     3.4  2.190890  4     3.2  1.483240
18  5     4.4  2.190890  4     3.6  2.190890  6     3.8  1.923538
19  3     4.8  1.483240  0     2.8  2.683282  5     3.8  1.923538
20  8     5.0  1.870829  3     3.4  2.190890  6     4.4  2.073644
21  2     4.4  2.302173  8     3.8  2.863564  8     5.8  1.483240
22  5     4.6  2.302173  4     3.8  2.863564  7     6.4  1.140175
23  8     5.2  2.774887  4     3.8  2.863564  4     6.0  1.581139
24  2     5.0  3.000000  1     4.0  2.549510  8     6.6  1.673320
25  7     4.8  2.774887  1     3.6  2.880972  5     6.4  1.816590
26  8     6.0  2.549510  3     2.6  1.516575  3     5.4  2.073644
27  5     6.0  2.549510  3     2.4  1.341641  6     5.2  1.923538
28  8     6.0  2.549510  6     2.8  2.049390  0     4.4  3.049590
29  8     7.2  1.303840  2     3.0  1.870829  1     3.0  2.549510
```

Comment: This is great! I did not know you could list the functions for agg. I will review the map operation to understand it better. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @Diego, glad i could help :)

Comment: When I use the code with a larger data set (2080 cols) for some reason the column order desired changed. All columns are computed fine but ordered differently (eg orig data: A, B. C. A/B, A/C...) output is A, A/B mean, A/B std, A/C mean, A/C std, A mean, A std...). I spent hours trying to understand what is going on...any hint on where to look at? Thanks !

Comment: Does the "/" after the A change the order? I tested and it changes the order !!! Puts A/ before A !!!