# Pandas column sort order

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am using rolling().agg and adding columns to a dataframe.

```
def add_mean_std_cols(df):
    res = df.rolling(5).agg(['mean','std'])

    res.columns = res.columns.map('_'.join)

    final = res.join(df).sort_index(axis=1)
    return final

np.random.seed(20)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,size=(10, 6)), columns=list('ABCDEF'))
print
print df
print
df.columns = ['A', 'A/B','AB', 'AC', 'C/B', 'D']

print add_mean_std_cols(df)
```

The issue is the output column name order:

```
   A  A/B  A/B_mean   A/B_std  AB  AB_mean    AB_std  AC  AC_mean    AC_std  A_mean     A_std  C/B  C/B_mean   C/B_std  D  D_mean     D_std
0  3    4       NaN       NaN   6      NaN       NaN   7      NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN    2       NaN       NaN  0     NaN       NaN
1  6    8       NaN       NaN   5      NaN       NaN   3      NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN    0       NaN       NaN  6     NaN       NaN
2  6    0       NaN       NaN   5      NaN       NaN   7      NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN    5       NaN       NaN  2     NaN       NaN
3  6    3       NaN       NaN   3      NaN       NaN   0      NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN    6       NaN       NaN  2     NaN       NaN
4  3    1       3.2  3.114482   8      5.4  1.816590   0      3.4  3.507136     4.8  1.643168    2       3.0  2.449490  7     3.4  2.966479
5  6    6       3.6  3.361547   8      5.8  2.167948   2      2.4  2.880972     5.4  1.341641    1       2.8  2.588436  3     4.0  2.345208
6  2    6       3.2  2.774887   4      5.6  2.302173   6      3.0  3.316625     4.6  1.949359    4       3.6  2.073644  8     4.4  2.880972
7  6    2       3.6  2.302173   3      5.2  2.588436   1      1.8  2.489980     4.6  1.949359    5       3.6  2.073644  2     4.4  2.880972
8  1    8       4.6  2.966479   2      5.0  2.828427   4      2.6  2.408319     3.6  2.302173    4       3.2  1.643168  8     5.6  2.880972
9  6    0       4.4  3.286335   3      4.0  2.345208   4      3.4  1.949359     4.2  2.489980    0       2.8  2.167948  5     5.2  2.774887
```

For some reason it is sorting A/B and AB before A_mean A_std.

The order that I would prefer is:

```
A  A_mean  A_std ...
```

From playing it seems that '_' is sorted last.

Any suggestions on how to achieve the desired order?

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46140511/5741205) help??

Comment: I posted the question before your last answer...though I am getting ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis.  I am checking it for any typos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [60]: res = df.rolling(5).agg(['mean','std'])

In [61]: res.columns = res.columns.map('_'.join)

In [62]: cols = np.concatenate(list(zip(df.columns, res.columns[0::2], res.columns[1::2])))

In [63]: res.join(df).loc[:, cols]
Out[63]:
   A  A_mean     A_std  A/B  A/B_mean   A/B_std  AB  AB_mean    AB_std  AC  AC_mean    AC_std  C/B  C/B_mean   C/B_std  D  D_mean  \
0  3     NaN       NaN    4       NaN       NaN   6      NaN       NaN   7      NaN       NaN    2       NaN       NaN  0     NaN
1  6     NaN       NaN    8       NaN       NaN   5      NaN       NaN   3      NaN       NaN    0       NaN       NaN  6     NaN
2  6     NaN       NaN    0       NaN       NaN   5      NaN       NaN   7      NaN       NaN    5       NaN       NaN  2     NaN
3  6     NaN       NaN    3       NaN       NaN   3      NaN       NaN   0      NaN       NaN    6       NaN       NaN  2     NaN
4  3     4.8  1.643168    1       3.2  3.114482   8      5.4  1.816590   0      3.4  3.507136    2       3.0  2.449490  7     3.4
5  6     5.4  1.341641    6       3.6  3.361547   8      5.8  2.167948   2      2.4  2.880972    1       2.8  2.588436  3     4.0
6  2     4.6  1.949359    6       3.2  2.774887   4      5.6  2.302173   6      3.0  3.316625    4       3.6  2.073644  8     4.4
7  6     4.6  1.949359    2       3.6  2.302173   3      5.2  2.588436   1      1.8  2.489980    5       3.6  2.073644  2     4.4
8  1     3.6  2.302173    8       4.6  2.966479   2      5.0  2.828427   4      2.6  2.408319    4       3.2  1.643168  8     5.6
9  6     4.2  2.489980    0       4.4  3.286335   3      4.0  2.345208   4      3.4  1.949359    0       2.8  2.167948  5     5.2

      D_std
0       NaN
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4  2.966479
5  2.345208
6  2.880972
7  2.880972
8  2.880972
9  2.774887
```

Comment: I am getting ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Answer (score 0):

You can [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) by `MultiIndex` and then [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
def add_mean_std_cols(df):
    res = df.rolling(5).agg(['mean','std'])

    df.columns = [df.columns, [''] * len(df.columns)]
    final = res.join(df).sort_index(axis=1)
    final.columns = final.columns.map('_'.join).str.strip('_')
    return final


print (add_mean_std_cols(df))

   A  A_mean     A_std  A/B  A/B_mean   A/B_std  AB  AB_mean    AB_std  AC  \
0  3     NaN       NaN    4       NaN       NaN   6      NaN       NaN   7   
1  6     NaN       NaN    8       NaN       NaN   5      NaN       NaN   3   
2  6     NaN       NaN    0       NaN       NaN   5      NaN       NaN   7   
3  6     NaN       NaN    3       NaN       NaN   3      NaN       NaN   0   
4  3     4.8  1.643168    1       3.2  3.114482   8      5.4  1.816590   0   
5  6     5.4  1.341641    6       3.6  3.361547   8      5.8  2.167948   2   
6  2     4.6  1.949359    6       3.2  2.774887   4      5.6  2.302173   6   
7  6     4.6  1.949359    2       3.6  2.302173   3      5.2  2.588436   1   
8  1     3.6  2.302173    8       4.6  2.966479   2      5.0  2.828427   4   
9  6     4.2  2.489980    0       4.4  3.286335   3      4.0  2.345208   4   

   AC_mean    AC_std  C/B  C/B_mean   C/B_std  D  D_mean     D_std  
0      NaN       NaN    2       NaN       NaN  0     NaN       NaN  
1      NaN       NaN    0       NaN       NaN  6     NaN       NaN  
2      NaN       NaN    5       NaN       NaN  2     NaN       NaN  
3      NaN       NaN    6       NaN       NaN  2     NaN       NaN  
4      3.4  3.507136    2       3.0  2.449490  7     3.4  2.966479  
5      2.4  2.880972    1       2.8  2.588436  3     4.0  2.345208  
6      3.0  3.316625    4       3.6  2.073644  8     4.4  2.880972  
7      1.8  2.489980    5       3.6  2.073644  2     4.4  2.880972  
8      2.6  2.408319    4       3.2  1.643168  8     5.6  2.880972  
9      3.4  1.949359    0       2.8  2.167948  5     5.2  2.774887
```

Comment: Problem is with your sample or with real data? What is your pandas version?

Comment: It gives AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: Hmmm, I believe there is problem in old version of pandas, because from version `0.16.0` `index.str.strip()` working nice - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#string-methods-enhancements

Comment: My version of pandas is 0.18.1

Comment: Hmmm, then I have no idea. for me it working perfectly in pandas 0.20.3.

Comment: Upgraded to 0.20.3. You are right, worked fine. Thanks!